# Do 'reduce' with results from Cloudant search?

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant

In Cloudant is it possible to do something like a reduce on a set of results from a search index (as opposed to a view)?

In my case, I'd like to find all documents that have a title value that includes 'foo', then for each of these sum the total number of views, based on each document's viewCount value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `reduce` but you can use faceting to get counts.

Example query
`?q=*:*&counts=["type"]`

Example response

```
{
  "total_rows":100000,
  "bookmark":"g...",
  "rows":[...],
  "counts":{
    "type":{
      "sofa": 10, 
      "chair": 100,
      "lamp": 97
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html#faceting

Comment: @bradenoble Couple of other questions... Can I just get counts and not rows? Can I get the sum total, rather than counts for each viewCount value?

Comment: For your first question, include the limit parameter and request 0 rows, like this: '?q=*:*&counts=["type"]&limit=0` and you'll get counts and no rows in the result.

For your second question, is that different than just taking the value from `total_rows` field?

Comment: limit=0 <= never thought of that! Thanks. By 'sum total' I meant getting (in my case) the total number of views for all documents that match a query, rather than having to get the counts and then calculate the total.

Comment: Does `total_rows` not do the job for you? (`total_rows` shows you the total number of hits of your query, not the total number of docs in the database.)

Comment: Just to clarify: each document represents a video, and each document has a viewCount field that represents the video's view count (the number of times the video was played). I need to sum the total value of all these views, not just the number of videos (documents) that match the query. Hope that makes sense!